# Rotate result text on submit

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to do a formular where user selects option how the result should be rotated on submit.
What I want is that on submit the selected value should rotate by 90deg or 45deg, depending on the selected option.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnsubmit").click(function(){
    var text = $("#sel1 option:selected").text();
    $("#result").text(text);
  });
  $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 90){
      $(this).val().css("transform","rotate(90deg)");
    }
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/index1337/pen/ZKPNyJ

Comment: Yes,Thank you very much!!!@MichaelCoker

Comment: @lonut you're welcome. You should reply to my answer though :) also once you feel the problem is solved, be sure to accept a solution (the checkmark by answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to apply the transform to `#result`. I would also make it `inline-block` so it rotates in place. Also added a `form` tag to your inputs, and disabled the `submit` event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $result = $('#result');
  $("#btnsubmit").click(function() {
    var text = $("#sel1 option:selected").text();
    $result.text(text);
  });
  $("input[type='radio']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 90) {
      $result.css("transform", "rotate(90deg)");
    } else {
      $result.css("transform", "rotate(45deg)");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#result {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="radio" value="90" name="rotate" class="90deg" />90deg
  <input type="radio" value="45" name="rotate" class="45deg" />45deg
  <select name="selection" id="sel1">
  <option value="1">90</option>
  <option value="2">45</option>
</select><br>
  <button name="submit" value="submit" id="btnsubmit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="result">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better solution that works for all browsers.
Rotation is done by adding and removing a class.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btnsubmit").click(function(){
       var text = $("#sel1 option:selected").text();
       $("#result").text(text);
   })
  $( "input[type='radio']" ).change(function() {
  if( $( this ).val() == 90) {
  $("#result").addClass("rotated90");
   $("#result").removeClass("rotated45");
  }else{
   $("#result").removeClass("rotated90")
   $("#result").addClass("rotated45");
  }
});
  
});
```

```css
.rotated90{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.rotated45{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#result{
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" value="90" name="rotate" class="90deg"/>90deg
<input type="radio" value="45" name="rotate" class="45deg"/>45deg
<select name="selection" id="sel1">
  <option value="1">90</option>
  <option value="2">45</option>
</select><br>
<button name="submit" value="submit" id="btnsubmit">Submit</button>
<div id="result">
</div>
```